# Default function implementation for linking

Tags: c

I have a family of executables pieced together from a set of .o files. There's some reusable ones, and then usually a couple of executable specific modules. One of the reusable pieces wants to provide a sort of "application hook". But many of the executables just do a standard no-op thing. While a couple of others actually want to define interesting behavior for said hook.

What would be ideal, is if there was a way to provide a standard default version of the function, which the linker would use if none of the other .o files defined said function, but if they did, use the others.

Is there any way/technique to approximate this sort of thing with just straight C?

Comment: You should read some documentation on weak symbols.

Comment: @Macmade , just read the Wikipedia page on them, thank you! Many of the examples I see involve creating libs (.so's). Is that by chance, or do they only work with libraries. Can I use them with just .o's ?

Comment: It's usually very useful for libraries. But it's "just" linker stuff, so you may of course use them without a shared library. But you may have hard time if multiple .o files are providing implementations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using GCC as your compiler, then you can declare the replaceable functions like this:

```
void foo() __attribute__ ((weak));
```

Here's an example on how this works. In your main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()__attribute__ ((weak))
{
    printf("%s", "Hidden foo\n");
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In another file, foo.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo()
{
    printf("%s", "foo\n");
}
```

Now when you only compile, link and run main.c, you'll get:

```
gcc main.c -o main
./main
Hidden foo
```

If you instead also compile foo.c, you'll get:

```
gcc main.c foo.c -o main
./main
foo
```

The weak version of foo() was replaced.

On a real setup, you would probably use a header file to provide the function prototypes:

```
void foo();
```

and then implement the weak version of those functions like this:

```
__attribute__ ((weak)) void foo()
{
    // ...
}
```

You could also use a macro to make this a bit more readable:

```
#define WEAK_SYMBOL __attribute__ ((weak))
```

So that you'll get:

```
WEAK_SYMBOL void foo() { /* ... */ }
```